# Why is this regex allowing a caret?

Tags: regex

http://regexr.com/3ars8

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-z])[0-9A-z-]{17}$
```

Should match "17 alphanumeric chars, hyphens allowed too, must include at least one letter and at least one number"

It'll correctly match:

```
ABCDF31U100027743
```

and correctly decline to match:

```
AB$DF31U100027743
```

(and almost any other non-alphanumeric char)

but will apparently allow:

```
AB^DF31U100027743
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Because your character class `[A-z]` matches this symbol.

`[A-z]` matches `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, `` ` ``, and the English letters.

Actually, it is a common mistake. You should use `[a-zA-Z]` instead to only allow English letters.

Here is a visualization from Expresso, showing what the range `[A-z]` actually covers:

[image: screenshot from Expresso showing the ASCII table, where you can see what the [A-z] range actually covers]

So, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/uD6fQ9/1) (with `i` option) won't capture your string.

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])[0-9a-z-]{17}$
```

In my opinion, it is always safer to use `Ignorecase` option to avoid such an issue and shorten the regex.

Answer (score 22):

> regex uses ASCII printable characters from the space to the tilde range.

Whenever we use `[A-z]` token it matches the following table highlighted characters. If we use `[ -~]` token  it matches starting from `SPACE` to tilde.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You're allowing A-z (capital 'A' through lower 'z'). You don't say what regex package you're using, but it's not necessarily clear that A-Z and a-z are contiguous; there could be other characters in between.  Try this instead:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z-]{17}$
```

It seems to meet your criteria for me in regexpal.